# Accessing a variable from setup() in (draw) in p5.js

Tags: p5.js, scoping

I am drawing a scatterplot with p5.js and want to access the `x` and `y` points from inside the `setup()` function for use with `mouseovers` in the `draw()` function. How can I make the `x` and `y` point variables globally accessible? I'm afraid I don't understand scoping well enough yet. Do they need to be initialized as arrays...?

```js
function setup() {
  //create canvas 
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  //loop through the videoDatatwo array of objects and get xpoints and ypoints
  for (var i = 0; i < videoDatatwo.length; i++) {

    videoDatatwo[i].xpoint = map(videoDatatwo[i].Reach, 0, 47674, 150, width - 400);
    videoDatatwo[i].ypoint = map(videoDatatwo[i].Views, 0, 9248, height - 150, 150);


  }

}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring your `videoDatatwo` variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a variable to be available in both the `setup()` and `draw()` functions, then you need to **declare** it outside of those functions. Here's an example:

```js
var message;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  message = 'hello world';
}

function draw() {
  text(message, 100, 100);
}
```

This code **declares** the `message` variable at the top of the sketch, then it **initializes** it in the `setup()` function, and finally it **references** it in the `draw()` function.

The same concept would apply to arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried declaring var videoDatatwo[i].xpoint and var videoDatatwo[i].ypoint but get an "[i] is not defined" message. How do I declare these variables correctly, and what is the logic?

Comment: PS I just realized my professor had put var videoDatatwo = []; in the html script so I tried moving it to the top of the js script but that didn't have the desired effect.